# Can't load EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, web-config

I just get every time this error:

I am using asp.net in visual studio 2015.Framework: 4.6.1

```
[ActivationException: IRepositoryService - 
LoaderExceptions information:
Kan bestand of assembly EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
]
```

But I already removed the EntityFramework from the csproj file. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{61E84A2C-3B35-466B-8B46-9AFF24D84FE9}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>verploegenbalie.nl</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>verploegenbalie.nl</AssemblyName>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Dynamicweb">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Dynamicweb\Dynamicweb.Admin\bin\Dynamicweb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Dynamicweb.Admin">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Dynamicweb\Dynamicweb.Admin\bin\Dynamicweb.Admin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Dynamicweb.AspNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Projects\Dynamicweb8724.nl\Dynamicweb8724.nl\bin\Dynamicweb.AspNet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Dynamicweb.Controls">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Dynamicweb\Dynamicweb.Admin\bin\Dynamicweb.Controls.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Dynamicweb.Searching">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Dynamicweb\Dynamicweb.Admin\bin\Dynamicweb.Searching.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>       
    <Reference Include="Glimpse.AspNet, Version=1.9.2.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Glimpse.AspNet.1.9.2\lib\net45\Glimpse.AspNet.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Glimpse.Core, Version=1.8.6.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Glimpse.1.8.6\lib\net45\Glimpse.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core.1.0.0-rc1-final\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Projects\Dynamicweb8724.nl\Dynamicweb8724.nl\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mobile" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryDelete.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryEdit.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryList.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategorySave.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CustomDealersearch_Edit.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerCopy.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerDelete.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerEdit.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerList.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerSave.aspx" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Module_CustomDealersearch.gif" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Module_CustomDealersearch_Small.gif" />
    <Content Include="CustomModules\HelloWorld\HelloWorld_Edit.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Default.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="x.gif" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryDelete.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryDelete.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryDelete.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryDelete.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryEdit.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryEdit.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryEdit.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryEdit.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryList.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryList.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategoryList.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategoryList.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategorySave.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategorySave.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CategorySave.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CategorySave.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CustomDealersearch_Edit.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CustomDealersearch_Edit.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\CustomDealersearch_Edit.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CustomDealersearch_Edit.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerCopy.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerCopy.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerCopy.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerCopy.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerDelete.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerDelete.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerDelete.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerDelete.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerEdit.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerEdit.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerEdit.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerEdit.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerList.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerList.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerList.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerList.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerSave.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerSave.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\DealerSave.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>DealerSave.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\Category.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\CategoryCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\Dealer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\DealerCollection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\DealerSQL.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\CustomDealersearch\Objects\Frontend.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\EcomCartCreatedObserver1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\HelloWorld\HelloWorld_Edit.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>HelloWorld_Edit.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="CustomModules\HelloWorld\HelloWorld_Edit.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>HelloWorld_Edit.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Default.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Web.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="CustomModules\ImportData\" />
    <Folder Include="CustomModules\NewOrder\" />
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>62846</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://verploegenbalie.nl</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

But the error doesnt go away

Thank you

Comment: Oke, I solved it. Just copied entityframework.dll as reference

Answer (score -1):

Oke, I solved it. Just copied entityframework.dll as reference – SavantTheIncredible just now   edit